# How to Effectively query in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have over 2000 Products in Realtime DB. You can see the Product structure 
below

[image]

But the Problem is that I need to query with 3 WHERE clauses.

> I need to get a Item WHERE CID = C09 && MID= S03 && SID= S03

I have referred the below question [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

I have worked on the first solution. But Category C09 has over 1000 products. I am downloading 1000 products to show 20 products.

I tried using Querybase. But it has an [issue](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase/issues/53).

So please suggest me an effective solution to query effectively.

**CODE**

```
var firstCat = firebase.database().ref('S01/Products').orderByChild("productCID").equalTo("C09");

  firstCat.once("value")
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;

        var MID = childSnapshot.child("productMID").val();
        var SID = childSnapshot.child("productSID").val();

         if (MID == "M03" && SID == "S03") {
          var ProductID = childSnapshot.child("productID").val();
          var name = childSnapshot.child("productName").val();
          var unit = childSnapshot.child("productUnit").val();
          var status = childSnapshot.child("productStatus").val();
          var productMRP = childSnapshot.child("productMRP").val();
          var price = childSnapshot.child("productSellingPrice").val();
          var buying_price = childSnapshot.child("productBuyingPrice").val();

         }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already be encoding the necessary values into the key of the items. Given that, you can use the key to find the matching children:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('S01/Products');
var query = allProducts.orderByKey().startAt("C09M03S03").endAt("C09M03S04");
query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshor.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key, child.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: How can i query "C09M03S09" where S09 has no endAt ID because it is the last category in my list ?

Comment: Just a `startAt()` would do that, or `endAt("~")` (which is just a character higher in the ASCII table than what you seem to use).